# verilog assignment compiler error

Tags: compiler-errors, variable-assignment, verilog

I have a basic compiler error I am not able to figure out.
Code:

```
module (input [127:0] in1,
        input [2:0] en);
real a1;
if(en==3'b001)
begin
  a1=$bitstoreal(in1[31:0]);
end
```

The error is :

```
Error: E:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0/examples/FloatingPt.v(20): near "=": syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting IDENTIFIER or TYPE_IDENTIFIER or '#' or '('
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have procedural code outside a procedural construct.

```
real a1;
initial
  begin
  if(en==3'b001)
    begin
    a1=$bitstoreal(in1[31:0]);
    end
  end
```

Comment: I dont want it inside an initial block. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Yes. Use a task or a function.

Comment: Take a look at this memory model. http://www.micron.com/get-document/?documentId=5243 -> Sim Models -> LPDDR Verilog Model. The model is mobile_ddr.v You can see how the model uses a few procedural blocks for high-level control and then calls tasks containing groups of calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Assignments in Verilog are done by the `assign` statement if you're trying to set the value of a `wire` or within a procedural block (`always` or `initial`) for other data types.

In your example, you are missing an `always` block:

```
always @(*) begin
    if(en==3'b001) begin
        a1=$bitstoreal(in1[31:0]);
    end
end
```

You also might have a problem assigning a bus to the `real` type if you're not sure of what you're doing. You might need to write it as `a1 = $itor(in1);`

Comment: If I dont want to include an always block, how do i do it?

Comment: its not possible to do continuous assignment for real types. I think they are implemented as registers.